# will it be still permissionsetAssignment exist even after the user is deactivated.?

Tags: permission-sets

I checked sandbox still i see the user who are inActive and the permission set exist for those user.

```
SELECT Id, permissionSet.Name, permissionSet.Id, AssigneeId  FROM
PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'Business_Manager'
AND Assignee.isActive = true
```

I only get one record from this query, and the user is inactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, PermissionSetAssignment, PermissionSetLicenseAssignment, and UserPackageLicense records persist even when the user is deactivated. In fact, we ended up writing a trigger to delete those records upon deactivation because we kept running out of UserPackageLicense assignments (the packages were limited to X number of licenses). However, the query as written should not have returned any inactive users, since you were filtering by Active. However, Frozen users would still appear in such a query, because Frozen users are still Active users.